# Hibernate Class Level Validation Without Annotation

Tags: hibernate-validator

I have a model module that is not dependent on anything (almost a standalone module), including the repository (the dependency goes the other way).
Now, I need to add some Hibernate validation that depends on data already in the database.
I cannot add a validator (annotation AND the actual validator class) in the model module, because I don't have access to the repository. So, I can only add them in the repository module, or in the other modules that have references to both of them (services, for example).

I've used the method as it is defined in the manual (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=6.0#section-programmatic-constraint-definition).

Something like this:

```
ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = this.validatorFactory.createConstraintMapping();
constraintMapping
            .type(<ModelClass>.class)
            .ignoreAnnotations(true)
            .constraintDefinition(<custom annotation>.class)
            .validatedBy(<custom validator>.class);
return this.validatorFactory
            .addMapping(constraintMapping)
            .buildValidatorFactory()
            .getValidator();
```

The model class itself doesn't have the annotation, it's only defined here, in the code.

In the end, my validator doesn't get called.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!